# how to find out one string contains substring in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am having one string variable need to check substring is present in it, like:

`str = "sdfgg"`

need to check if `str` contains `df`

Please help me to write a code in ruby to check the scenario

Comment: Haven't you read the [Ruby String class documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html)?

Comment: "Things"? If the documentation is not working for you, you might have a hard time with Ruby. If your code that you wrote after reading the documentation is not working for you, you should post the said code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String#include?`.

```
str.include?("df")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regex for that:

```
if str =~ /df/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```